# Don't print if array is not full

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
array('apples', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'watermelons', 'bananas');
```

And I don't want to print this array if there are only apples and oranges in it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at this [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542694/in-array-multiple-values):

```
$haystack = array(...);

$target = array('foo', 'bar');

if(count(array_intersect($haystack, $target)) == count($target)){
    // all of $target is in $haystack
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take out the apples and oranges and see if there is anything left.

```
$arr = array('apples', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'watermelons', 'bananas');
$arrDiff = array_diff($arr, array('apples', 'oranges')); //take out the apples and oranges

if(!empty($arrDiff)) //there's something other than apples and oranges in the array
    print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I'd do `if (!empty($arrDiff))`, arguably a bit more intuitive to read

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array('apples', $array) && in_array('oranges', $array) && count($array) == 2)
{
    // Don't print array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance the number of elements to go into the array, then you can do:

```
<?php
$expectedCount = 5; //in this example, we are looking for five elements in our array
if(count($array) == $expectedCount)
{
    var_dump($array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first specify the minimum amount of element the array must have for example in this case its 5 
then use function count() whos reference can be found in http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

```
if(count(array) >= 5)
```

{

```
  //perform action
```

}