# Find multiple array inside a single array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a = 'red';
$b = 'blue'; 
$colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black'];
```

I am trying to check if **both** `$a`, and `$b` are present in `$colors` 
If yes, return `true` else return `false`

I could obviously do

```
if(in_array($a, $colors) && in_array($b, $colors)){
  //true
}
```

But, I am hoping for an array function that can do both in on call, or any method simpler than that. I tried with `array_intersect()` to no avail.

Comment: No. *Confirm the existence of multiple values inside an array*

Comment: @undefined You are wrong. I check that link before even asking this. It is two entirely different question.

Comment: What was the problem with `array_intersect()` ?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542694/in-array-multiple-values. It looks like your question has already been asked.

Comment: @ShengSlogar Yes, it does seem to have been answered. Not sure if all the answers I have seen so far provider simpler solutions to the example I have posted so-far

Comment: Look at the accepted answer to the link I gave you. It uses ``array_intersect`` and it is the easiest way I've found as it dosen't use && for each wanted value.

Comment: Thanks but I have went with && to get the job done, as it calls less functions resulting to less overhead of the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_intersect()` should have worked, but you may also try `array_diff()`. If the result is an empty array, then every element of the first array was found in the second array.

```
<?php
if(count(array_diff(array($a, $b), $colors)) == 0)
{
// Both found
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$c = array($a, $b);
if (count(array_intersect($c, $colors)) === count($c)) {
     // ...
}
```