# check multiple values using in_array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have a scenario as follows where I need to check value exists in array or not using in_array

```
$allRecordTypes =  array('new','newly','brandnew','branded');
$tempRecordTypes = array('new','newly');
$RecordType = in_array($tempRecordTypes,$allRecordTypes);
```

I'm sure that the above code is not correct, but I need to check whether the `$tempRecordTypes` need to be checked with `$allRecordTypes`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in\_array multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542694/in-array-multiple-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to see what values are in both arrays. `in_array()` checks to see if *one value* exists in an array so that won't work for you (unless you use a loop to iterate through your `$tempRecordTypes` array and compare it to the `$allRecordTypes` array).

```
$RecordType = array_intersect($tempRecordTypes,$allRecordTypes);
```