# hide anchor for array elements

Tags: php, codeigniter

> I have two arrays like given below from these two arrays I am getting
>   missing element that is also given below:

```
$news=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

$new=[1,2,4,6,7];

$missing=[3,5];
```

> I want when I have two values or multi-values in that case if the condition
>   should work and for another value else part to be executed

```
if(in_array($news,$missing))
{
echo "ok";
}
else
{
echo "no";
}
```

> case would be :[3] ,[5] and [3,5];
>
> I want if array value =3 output should be no if value=5 output should
>   be=no if both then also output should be no but when value is
>   different like [4] or [4,6] output would be ok;

```
can anyone please help me related this I am stuck here. Or is there any way to solve this kind of problems
```

Comment: I think you should pass $new in in_array() not $news then your condition will work.

Comment: I think you should pass `$new in in_array($new,$missing)` not `in_array($news,$missing)` then your condition will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in\_array multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542694/in-array-multiple-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
count(array_intersect($news,$missing))
```

If count > 0 means there is atleast one element in both arrays, so answer will be **no**. It count = 0, means both arrays have different values, so answer will be **ok**.

Comment: Instead of in_array() use my given function