# check multiple values from checkbox in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this form :

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="0" id="check_list">- 0<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="1" id="check_list">- 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="2" id="check_list">- 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="3" id="check_list">- 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="4" id="check_list">- 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="5" id="check_list">- 5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="6" id="check_list">- 6<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="7" id="check_list">- 7<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Now I wont to check the result from this form ,, if result have (2,3,6) we need to do something, and if result have value (2,3) we need to do something, and if result have value (2) we need to do something, and if result have value (3) we need to do something,and if result have value (6) we need to do something,

How can do that in php ?

I try this but not work good with me

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {

    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
    if ($check =='2' && $check =='3' && $check =='6'){
        // do something
    } elseif ($check =='2' && $check =='3'){
        // do something
    } elseif ($check =='6'){
        // do something
    } elseif ($check =='3'){
        // do something
    } elseif ($check =='2'){
        // do something
    }
}
}
```

Also i try this and not do any thing

```
if(in_array(array(2,3,6),$_POST['check_list'])){ 
// not work
} elseif(in_array(array(2,3),$_POST['check_list'])){ 
// not work
} elseif(in_array(array(2),$_POST['check_list'])){ 
// work
} elseif(in_array(array(3),$_POST['check_list'])){ 
// work
} elseif(in_array(array(7),$_POST['check_list'])){ 
// work
}
```

Comment: `$_POST[check_list]` will be an array you can use

Comment: Have you tried using a switch statement http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Do you think `if` use?

Comment: @smith see my update ,,,

Comment: `if ($check =='2' && $check =='3' && $check =='6'){` how can $check be more than one thing at a time?

Comment: @Özgür-can-karagöz yes ,, see my update

Comment: @smith so what can i do ?

Comment: Also : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: @eliot-k not good with me ,, because i have multi value !!

Comment: @smith i try `if(in_array(array(2,3,6),$_POST['check_list'])){ ...} `but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    if(
        has_values(Array(2,3,6), $_POST['check_list'])
    ){
        //Do what you need to do

    }else if(
        has_values(Array(2,3), $_POST['check_list'])
    ){
        //Do what you need to do

    }else if(
        has_values(Array(2), $_POST['check_list'])
    ){
        //Do what you need to do

    }
}else{
    //no checkboxes have been set
}

function has_values($testValues, $arrValues){
/*
    testValues is a 1 dimensional array (needles)
    arrValues is a 1 dimensional array that takes the array of set checkboxs ( haystack )
*/
    foreach ($testValues as $key => $value) {
        if(!in_array($value, $arrValues)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Developer notes
in_array is not type dependent.

if a checkbox is not checked the $_POST['check_list'] index will changes

Comment: i think `array_diff` or `array_intersect` is probably better, but this will work so you can have my vote.

Answer (score 1):

In short, when you submit the form you'll have an array `$_POST['check_list']` that contains the elements you've checked. So, if you check 2, 3 and 6, `$_POST['check_list'] = [2, 3, 6]`. Note that if you don't check any options, `$_POST['check_list']` will not exist.

Then you can use `if (in_array(2, $_POST['check_list'])) {...}` to do what you want if 2 is checked, for example.

Comment: what about if i have 2,3,6 ? how can use it in in_array ??

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040612/2014507)

Comment: @GutierrezPS comparing $_POST['check_list'] will not work as intended if other options are checked. use the empty function to check if $_POST['check_list'] has been set.

Comment: @abukotsh `in_array(2, $array) && in_array(3, $array) && in_array(6, $array)`