# Can you please explain in simple English what this php line means?

Tags: php, wordpress

What does the below php line of code mean please?

I am trying to understand how the below code impacts the behaviour of the template-parts/post/content.php file in wordpress.

```
<?php if ( is_single() && ! empty( $category_array ) && !in_array(2, $category_array ) ) : ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

"If the page we're on is [showing a single post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/), and the post has categories, and none of the categories are category #2..."

Comment: Well it could be any array of categories which is not empty and contains category #2 :p

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. If I wanted to add more categories to category 2, should I just add them with a comma? ex. array(2,5

Comment: Sorry, revising my answer to your comment; No, looks like you'd need separate `in_array` statements in sequence.

Comment: so for example - adding && !in_array(3, $category_array ) ?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, that should do it.

Comment: If you need many categories to be excluded - you could write an intersect like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040612/4244684