# Filter a multidimensional array by multiple, required values regardless of keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-filter

I have an multidimensional array and i'd like to filter by many values.

```
$datas = [
    [
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'gender' => 'male'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'gender' => 'female'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'gender' => 'female'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'gender' => 'male'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 7216,
        'first_name' => 'Mike',
        'last_name' => 'Lill',
        'gender' => 'male'
    ]
];
```

I have combined the methods of `array_filter` and `array_search` and got a good result but this only does the filtering of only one value. I'd like something like this...

```
array_filter(
    $datas,
    function ($key) {
        return array_search(['Doe', 'male'...], $key);
});
```

And its give

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'gender' => 'male'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'gender' => 'male'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can simply loop any given input and check if a given element matches any criteria you implement:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'gender' => 'male'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'gender' => 'female'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'gender' => 'female'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'gender' => 'male'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 7216,
        'first_name' => 'Mike',
        'last_name' => 'Lill',
        'gender' => 'male'
    ]
];

$needles = ['Doe', 'male'];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($element) use ($needles, &$output) {
    $matches = true;
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (!in_array($needle, $element)) {
            $matches = false;
        }
    }
    if ($matches) {
        $output[] = $element;
    }
});

print_r($output);
```

The obvious output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2135
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Doe
            [gender] => male
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5623
            [first_name] => Peter
            [last_name] => Doe
            [gender] => male
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

You wish to filter your multidimensional array based on multiple qualifying values irrespective of their keys.

If `$datas` is coming from a database, you should be performing this filtration in your sql to avoid needlessly squandering resources.

If you must filter in php, then `array_filter()` is an intuitive and logical function to call upon.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vXSTj))

```
$needles = ['Doe', 'male'];

var_export(
    array_filter($datas, function($row) use ($needles) {
        return !array_diff($needles, $row);
    })
);
```

`array_filter()` processes a boolean value in each `return` as it iterates the rows. `array_intersect($needles, $row)` will only keep the `$needles` elements which are present in the current row.  If the original `$needles` contains the same data as the filtered `$needles` then return `true` (keep the row).

From PHP7.4 and higher, you can use arrow syntax:

```
var_export(
    array_filter($datas, fn($row) => !array_diff($needles, $row)
);
```

Output: (from either snippet)

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2135,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'gender' => 'male',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 5623,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'gender' => 'male',
  ),
)
```

Note that the original first-level keys are preserved.  If your project requires the multidimensional array to be reindexed, write the `array_filter()` call inside of `array_values()`.

---

If you'd like some other techniques for the sake of running your own benchmarks with your own data, these language constructs will also provide filtration: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/C8ujq))

```
foreach ($datas as $row) {
    if (!array_diff($needles, $row)) { // all needles found
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}
var_export($result);  // reindexed already
```

and

```
foreach ($datas as $index => $row) {
    if (array_diff($needles, $row)) { // one or more needles not found
        unset($datas[$index]);
    }
}
var_export($datas);
```

---

For best efficiency, implement a nested loop with `in_array()` calls. It may seem counterintuitive to make so many iterated function calls, but the conditional `continue` allows the time complexity to be optimized and therefore delivers a better "[little o](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1364444/2943403)" because it can stop iterating as soon as a needle is not found.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PaDl9)) ([`array_filter()` Demo](https://3v4l.org/nvmBJ))

```
foreach ($datas as $row) {
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (!in_array($needle, $row)) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $result[] = $row;
}
var_export($result);
```

I should also point to [this related page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7542694/2943403) (which has an unfortunately vague problem statement).  I do not endorse a few of the techniques there (including the accepted answer), but there is certainly a technical relationship between these two pages.